# Editar ações de botões do modal de forma programatica

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

Estou criando um botão de forma programatica que assim que clicado, ira chamar um modal, porém, gostaria que assim que apertassem o botão de dentro do modal, a pagina reiniciasse e fechasse esse modal. Como eu faço a implementação?
sempre que eu coloco um .onClick = 'window.location.reload' com o id do botão do modal para reinciar a pagina assim que apertar no botão do MODAL, essa açaõ é acionada antes mesmo de chegar nessa parte, pois esta como ação do botão que aciona o modal, e não como ação do botão do modal em si.

--------------------------------------------------------- COMEÇO HTML ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    <!-- Modal 1 -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="registraDespesa" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div id="modal_titulo_div">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal_titulo">Erro na gravação</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modal_conteudo"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="modal_botao" data-dismiss="modal"> Voltar e corrigir </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- Fim modal 1 -->
```

------------------------------------------------------- FIM HTML --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
let btn = document.createElement('button')
        btn.className = 'btn btn-danger' // Colocando uma classe na tag
        btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>' // Colocando um elemento dentro da tag
        btn.id = 'id_despesa'+d.id // Pegando o id criado dentro do objeto despesa
        btn.onclick = function() {
            let id = this.id.replace('id_despesa','') // Retirando o id_despesa
            bd.remover(id)
            
        // Editando o modal que sera exibido 
        document.getElementById('modal_titulo').innerHTML= 'Erro!'
        document.getElementById('modal_titulo_div').className = 'modal-header text-danger'
        document.getElementById('modal_conteudo').innerHTML = 'Erro na gravação. Verifique se todos os campos foram preenchidos.'
        document.getElementById('modal_botao').innerHTML = 'V'
        
        // A grande duvida logo aqui
        document.getElementById('modal_botao').onclick = window.location.reload() // O onclick esta referenciando o botão que chama o modal, não o botão do proprio modal
        
        document.getElementById('modal_botao').className = 'btn btn-danger'
        $('#registraDespesa').modal('show')
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sempre que o nome de uma função for usada seguida de `()`, ela estará sendo invocada, executando aquilo que está definido em seu corpo. Neste caso você não está compartilhando o comportamento da função nativa `location.reload`, mas invocando-a sempre que o seu código é executado no navegador. Atribua uma função à propriedade `onclick` desta forma:

```
document.getElementById('modal_botao').onclick = function() { window.location.reload() }
```